# New to html,css, and javascript. I am having trouble passing variables to my javascript function from a drop down menu onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I assume I am making a syntax error, but not able to find an example close to mine on google. Would love any help anyone is willing to provide. I just started working in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript today. I thought it might be how I am passing the values to the function. However when I look up passing values it seems like functionName(value) is the correct format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script>
    // Function to change webpage background color
    function changeBodyBg(color){
        document.body.style.background = color;
    }
</script>
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg(red)">Red</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg(blue)">Blue</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg(green)">Green</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply need single quotes `''` around your string function arguments. When you use just a color name, your code is looking for a variable *named* `red`/ `green`/ `blue`, and not interpreting it as a string.

```html
<a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg('red')">Red</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg('blue')">Blue</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg('green')">Green</a>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script>
    // Function to change webpage background color
    function changeBodyBg(color){
        document.body.style.background = color;
    }
</script>
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg('red')">Red</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg('blue')">Blue</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg('green')">Green</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a string to a function as a parameter it needs to be in quotes. If your function is already in double quotes, you can use single quotes to pass the string. Like this -

```
onclick="changeColor('myColor')"
```

So the correct syntax will be

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg('red')">Red</a>
     <a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg('blue')">Blue</a>
     <a href="#" onclick="changeBodyBg('green')">Green</a>
   </div>
</div>
```